# Save changes done by javascript to a table (gridview)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` with empty cells. Whenever a cell is clicked I replace the contents of the cell (`innerHTML` property) with a string, using `javascript`.

I would like to save this changes on a 2d array when the index of my `combobox` is changed. However when I traverse the `gridview` during my `selectedindexchanged` event, none of the changes I did to the cells are visible (all the cells are empty). I guess the changes are not persistent.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the changes are not persistent. You should do some reading about how forms on the web work--not just specific to asp.net--to get a fuller understanding. Basically, your SelectedIndexChanged event is really a POST of a form on your page. Only form values, like those in `<input>` or `<select>` fields will be sent to the server and be available to process in your C# code. So, one option would be to have a hidden input for every cell in your GridView. Another one would be to have a single hidden input which stores a string representation of a 2d array, and you would manipulate that with JavaScript every time you change the contents of a cell. Then, when you process this data in your C# code, you'll need to process the hidden inputs, not the cells of the GridView.